# Objective-C messaging

Tags: objective-c, messaging

I am having trouble to understand the concept of private instance variables in Objective-C:

Let's assume I have a class:

```
@interface Dog : NSObject
```

and two declared selectors

```
- (void)setSomeString:(NSString *)_someString;
- (NSString *)someString;
```

in the Dog.m implementation file I declare a private instance variable:

```
@interface Dog()
{
  NSString *someString;
}
```

in the main method of the program I create a new dog object:

```
Dog *myDog = [[Dog alloc] init];
```

Why is it possible to do something like this out of the main method?

```
myDog.someString = @"Yoda";
```

I would expect the someString-variable to be private and only accessible by its setter

```
[myDog setSomeString:@"Yoda"];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use dot-syntax you are actually calling method `setSomeString`, the difference is just in syntax, not in meaning :)

Check [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html) about sending a message to an object

Comment: It is calling it automatically? Isn't that confusing. I was reading the Apple Doc but I found it somewhat unclear.

Comment: Ah okay I see 'a dot operator offers a compact and conveniant syntax for invoking an object's accessor method. The dot operator is often used in conjunction with the declared properties feature (...)'

Answer (score 0):

dot notation is just an abbreviation,

```
self.someVariable = newValue
//is the same as 
[self setSomeVariable:newValue];
```

and

```
currentValue = self.someVariable;
//is the same as
currentValue = [self someVariable];
```

Answer (score 0):

the dot syntax actually calls the setter method. To access the iVar, you can use the arrow syntax `->`

Comment: Which will not compile for a private or protected ivar.

Comment: that is correct, I was just saying that's how it could be done. You would need to declare the ivars as @public